# postgres key is not present in table constraint

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, postgresql-9.5

When trying to ALTER TABLE in Postgres 9.5 to create foreign key constraint: from `product_template.product_brand_id` to `product_brand.id`

```
ALTER TABLE public.product_template
    ADD CONSTRAINT product_template_product_brand_id_fkey 
    FOREIGN KEY (product_brand_id)
    REFERENCES public.product_brand (id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

Returns error

```
ERROR:  insert or update on table "product_template" violates foreign key         constraint "product_template_product_brand_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (product_brand_id)=(12) is not present in table "product_brand".
STATEMENT:  ALTER TABLE "product_template" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("product_brand_id") REFERENCES "product_brand" ON DELETE set null
```

Im confused why postgres is trying to find `product_brand.product_brand_id`, when the fkey is from `product_template.product_brand_id` to `product_brand.id`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error message simply states that there is at least one row in the table `product_template` that contains the value `12` in the column `product_brand_id`

But there is no corresponding row in the table `product_brand` where the column `id` contains the value `12`

`Key (product_brand_id)=(12)` relates the *source* column of the foreign key, not the target column.

Comment: Can't we allow to add the foreign key constraint though there are such values in the column which are not present in the foreign table?

Comment: @aagjalpankaj: if you want to allow invalid data, then don't add the constraint

Comment: I have to add FK constraint but wanted to ignore the existing values and the constraint should work for future values. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: No, you either need to delete those rows completely or set the FK column to NULL

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, the **value of FOREIGN KEY**(product_brand_id) provided in your ALTER statement is **not present in the source (product_brand) table**.